# Why does this volume averaging AutoHotKey program yield irrational results?

Tags: math, audio, autohotkey, volume, date-arithmetic

I have written the following AutoHotKey program to measure the "average volume" of the computer's audio over a window of time.  The window starts when the b key is pressed, and ends when the e key is pressed.  The intent is to use the program to objectively compare the volume of one copy of a song to another (i.e. on Youtube or Soundcloud).  I also added code to track the average volume of each minute within the window (the final "minute" being the remaining fraction of a minute).

The problem is that only the first minute's results are sensible.  If the overall window is larger than a minute, then it too yields an incoherent result.  Below is the output of a trial execution, after running the program for a bit more than two minutes.

Overall Left Volume:  1.354168
Overall Right Volume:  1.359160

Section 1 Left:  0.528259
Section 1 Right:  0.529830

Section 2 Left:  1.097612
Section 2 Right: 1.101604

Section 3 Left:  63.397783
Section 3 Right:  63.656189

Each value should always be between 0 and 1, as the volume numbers are stored as such.  Where might my logic have gone wrong?

```
; These two lines increase script speed
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines, -1

; Include the Vista Audio library
#Include VA.ahk

audioMeter := VA_GetAudioMeter()
VA_IAudioMeterInformation_GetMeteringChannelCount(audioMeter, channelCount)
VA_GetDevicePeriod("capture", devicePeriod)

lSamples := []
rSamples := []
lSamplesTotal := 0
rSamplesTotal := 0
lSamplesMinuteAverageList := []
rSamplesMinuteAverageList := []
boolIsOn := False

~e::boolIsOn := False

while boolIsOn == False
{
    ~b::
    boolIsOn := True

    while boolIsOn == True
    {
        lSamplesMinuteTotal := 0
        rSamplesMinuteTotal := 0
        numLSamples := 0
        numRSamples := 0 ; These two variables track the number of entries in lSamples and rSamples generated during the current minute

        minuteStart := A_TickCount

        while (A_TickCount - minuteStart) < 60000 && boolIsOn == True
        {
            VA_IAudioMeterInformation_GetPeakValue(audioMeter, peakValue)    
            VarSetCapacity(peakValues, channelCount * 4)
            VA_IAudioMeterInformation_GetChannelsPeakValues(audioMeter, channelCount, &peakValues)

            lValue := NumGet(peakValues, 0, "float")
            rValue := NumGet(peakValues, 4, "float")

            lSamples.Insert(lValue)
            numLSamples++

            rSamples.Insert(rValue)
            numRSamples++

            Sleep, %devicePeriod%
        }

        Loop, % lSamples.MaxIndex()
        {
            lSamplesMinuteTotal += lSamples[A_Index]
            lSamplesTotal += lSamples[A_Index]
        }

        lSamplesMinuteAverage := lSamplesMinuteTotal / numLSamples

        Loop, % rSamples.MaxIndex()
        {
            rSamplesMinuteTotal += rSamples[A_Index]
            rSamplesTotal += rSamples[A_Index]
        }

        rSamplesMinuteAverage := rSamplesMinuteTotal / numRSamples

        lSamplesMinuteAverageList.Insert(lSamplesMinuteAverage)
        rSamplesMinuteAverageList.Insert(rSamplesMinuteAverage)
        ToolTip, % lSamplesMinuteAverage "`n" rSamplesMinuteAverage
    }

    lSamplesAverage := lSamplesTotal / lSamples.MaxIndex()
    rSamplesAverage := rSamplesTotal / rSamples.MaxIndex()

    messageBoxText := "Overall Left Volume:  " lSamplesAverage "`nOverall Right Volume:  " rSamplesAverage "`n"

    while A_Index <= lSamplesMinuteAverageList.MaxIndex() || A_Index <= rSamplesMinuteAverageList.MaxIndex()
    {
        messageBoxText .= "`n`nSection " A_Index " Left:  " lSamplesMinuteAverageList[A_Index] "`nSection " A_Index " Right:  " rSamplesMinuteAverageList[A_Index]
    }

    MsgBox, % messageBoxText

    lSamples := []
    rSamples := []
    lSamplesTotal := 0
    rSamplesTotal := 0
    lSamplesMinuteAverageList := []
    rSamplesMinuteAverageList := []

    return
}

return
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you have logic issues, but I don't think this line is syntactically correct: `while A_Index <= lSamplesMinuteAverageList.MaxIndex[] || A_Index <= rSamplesMinuteAverageList.MaxIndex[]`, it should be `rSamplesMinuteAverageList.MaxIndex()`

Comment: Also, you want to use `.=` instead of `+=` to append text on line 84.

Comment: Thank you for that, that solved a different problem I was having.  I made the changes to the code and added an example to clarify the main problem as well.